# salmon + microwave = BLAM, any suggestions?

Tags: microwave

Salmon fillets tend to go 'pop' and spatter bits of themselves around the container in the microwave. Anyone got a procedure that discourages this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Besides not microwaving it? Cover your filets with a paper towel, it will catch any exploding bits.

Seriously though, it shouldn't take but 6-8 minutes to sear a refrigerated salmon filet in a hot pan. Do this, your taste buds will thank you.

Comment: Usually I bake to avoid the boom, but this also sounds good.

Answer (score 14):

You can simulate steaming in a microwave. First defrost the salmon. Put it in a glass dish. Put some soy sauce on the bottom of the dish, say half a cm deep. Add some chopped ginger. Cover the dish with plastic wrap. Microwave for 5 minutes or so. Tastes great and healthly too.

Comment: You can also replace the soy sauce with lemon juice, and the chopped ginger with fresh herbs. Certainly not the best way to cook fish fillets, but a quick and still tasty and healthy way. This is useful when you're in places with only a microwave, e.g. at some workplace "kitchens"!

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to cook en papillote, (wrapped in partchment) such as in [this](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/salmon-fillet-en-papillote-with-julienne-vegetable-recipe/index.html) recipe. There is no shame using a microwave for serious culinary endeavors as long as you don't ask it to do what it can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. Don't use the microwave. Yes, the tool is useful for certain things--defrosting, reheating, or indeed making french fries (per a lovely blog). It is categorically *not* useful for cooking from raw.
Use a pan, your oven, or a grill.

Comment: @roux - do you have a link for the french fries in the microwave?

Comment: Not handy.. it's somewhere at http://www.playingwithfireandwater.com/

Comment: WARNING: that blog may cause you to be late for work, ignore sleep, and pay no attention to your significant other. You may also wish to cover your keyboard with a tarp to prevent damage from the amount of saliva you will drool.

Comment: Found the link. http://www.playingwithfireandwater.com/foodplay/2009/03/umami-burger.html  Pdf at the bottom of the page.

Comment: that blog is unreal. i've spent hours on that site, she's incredibly creative and talented.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until I cut the the power down to half normal. And it only takes about 3-4 minutes for a filet of fish.

Answer (score 1):

I would try reducing the cooking time. I was having this problem with Tallapia and found that reducing the cook time from 4min to about 2:30 fixed the problem. It comes out great!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean salmon in 4-6 ounce fillet pieces. Boiling fish juices and bubbling fat makes salmon explode. Jab some holes in the salmon with the tip of a sharp knife before you cook it.You don't need to cut it into pieces. Be sure to cross the muscles with the knife when you make the jabs. Put some holes in the sides of the fish too. Keep an eye on it as it microwaves. You'll probably have to re-jab the fish as it microwaves.